# Undefined References When Installing Backyard Brains' "Spike Recorder"

Tags: software-installation, 16.10

I'm trying to install Backyard Brains' "Spike Recorder" (https://github.com/BackyardBrains/Spike-Recorder). I've resolved the dependencies. But now I'm getting "undefined reference" errors (full output at https://hastebin.com/ijevavebob.pas). Is there a way for me to resolve these errors? I haven't gotten responses on GitHub or from the company's support (I only posted the issue yesterday). How can I resolve this problem.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 Gnome

Comment: It looks like the `Makefile` is simply missing the following objects from its `OBJECTS` list: `src/engine/AudioInputConfig.o`, `src/widgets/HorizontalColorPicker.o`, `src/widgets/HorizontalNumberPicker.o`, `src/widgets/TouchDropDownList.o`, `src/CalibrationWindow.o`

Comment: Okay, so how do I resolve that problem?

Comment: ... open up the Makefile and add them

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, but I see that a missing object is src/engine/AudioInputConfig.o. I don't find that, but I do find /src/engine AudioInputConfig.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Makefile` in a text editor and add the bolded elements below:

```
OBJECTS = \
    src/engine/AudioInputConfig.o \
    src/engine/RecordingManager.o \
    src/engine/AnalysisManager.o \
    src/engine/FileRecorder.o \
    src/engine/Player.o \
    src/engine/ArduinoSerial.o \
    src/engine/SpikeSorter.o \
    src/engine/SpikeAnalysis.o \
    src/engine/BASSErrors.o \
    src/engine/FileReadUtil.o \
    src/engine/FFTBackend.o \
    src/engine/HIDUsbManager.o \
    src/engine/EkgBackend.o \
    src/engine/FilterBase.o \
    src/engine/HighPassFilter.o \
    src/engine/LowPassFilter.o \
    src/engine/NotchFilter.o \
    src/widgets/LayoutItem.o \
    src/widgets/BoxLayout.o \
    src/widgets/Widget.o \
    src/widgets/Painter.o \
    src/widgets/PushButton.o \
    src/widgets/DropDownList.o \
    src/widgets/ScrollBar.o \
    src/widgets/Application.o \
    src/widgets/BitmapFontGL.o \
    src/widgets/TextureGL.o \
    src/widgets/LoadTexture.o \
    src/widgets/Label.o \
    src/widgets/ErrorBox.o \
    src/widgets/TextInput.o \
    src/widgets/RangeSelector.o \
    src/widgets/SwitchLayout.o \
    src/widgets/ToolTip.o \
    src/widgets/Plot.o \
    src/widgets/TabBar.o \
    src/widgets/HorizontalColorPicker.o \
    src/widgets/HorizontalNumberPicker.o \
    src/widgets/TouchDropDownList.o \
    src/DropDownList.o \
    src/Log.o \
    src/Game.o \
    src/main.o \
    src/MainView.o \
    src/AudioView.o \
    src/ConfigView.o \
    src/AnalysisView.o \
    src/AnalysisAudioView.o \
    src/AnalysisTrainList.o \
    src/AnalysisPlots.o \
    src/CalibrationWindow.o \
    src/RecordingBar.o \
    src/ColorDropDownList.o \
    src/FFTView.o \
    src/ThresholdPanel.o
```

Comment: I think steeldriver helped me make some progress. But now I get "Makefile:9: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop." I saved the original makefile, but renamed it makefile_original. The contents of my edited Makefile https://hastebin.com/exiqidezah.tex.

Comment: Please make sure you included the `\\` characters after each added object file exactly as shown (they are essential for proper line continuation)

Comment: Okay, I added a missing "\" at the end of the very last item in "OBJECTS = \
" so now it is "src/ThresholdPanel.o \"
Since you mentioned that. Is the below okay? or does there need to be a "\" after "src/native/PathsLinux.o" ... 
"OBJECTS_LINUX = \ 
 src/widgets/native/FileDialogLinux.o \
 src/native/PathsLinux.o" 
I'm not a programmer, maybe the last item doesn't even need the "\" in either of those two cases.

Comment: No the last item should not have a backslash after it - it is not being continued. Where present, a backslash must be the **last** character on the line - i.e. *no trailing whitespace*. If in doubt, simply copy-paste what I posted above into your Makefile in place of the existing `OBJECTS` list.

Comment: I copy pasted the OBJECTS list and I still get "Makefile:9: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop."https://hastebin.com/lahapahule.tex

Comment: The `OBJECTS` list in your hastebin appears to be truncated - please make sure to scroll down and select **everything** exactly as I posted above. Also please make sure you use a plain text editor (not a word processing application) to avoid the possibility of introducing non ASCII characters.

Comment: Victory! It's working.
A final version of the working code with an edited OBJECTS list in Makefile is here https://hastebin.com/lahapahule.tex