# "recipe commences before first target. Stop" Backyard Brains' "Spike Recorder"

Tags: compiling, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to install Backyard Brains' "Spike Recorder" on my Ubuntu 16.10 Gnome laptop. I've resolved some problems but now I'm getting the error "recipe commences before first target. Stop".

```
CCX = g++
CC  = gcc

TARGET = SpikeRecorder
TARGETDIR = SpikeRecorder

OBJECTS = \
    src/engine/AudioInputConfig.o \
    src/engine/RecordingManager.o \
    src/engine/AnalysisManager.o \
    src/engine/FileRecorder.o \
    src/engine/Player.o \
    src/engine/ArduinoSerial.o \
    src/engine/SpikeSorter.o \
    src/engine/SpikeAnalysis.o \
    src/engine/BASSErrors.o \
    src/engine/FileReadUtil.o \
    src/engine/FFTBackend.o \
    src/engine/HIDUsbManager.o \
    src/engine/EkgBackend.o \
    src/engine/FilterBase.o \
    src/engine/HighPassFilter.o \
    src/engine/LowPassFilter.o \
    src/engine/NotchFilter.o \
    src/widgets/LayoutItem.o \
    src/widgets/BoxLayout.o \
    src/widgets/Widget.o \
    src/widgets/Painter.o \
    src/widgets/PushButton.o \
    src/widgets/DropDownList.o \
    src/widgets/ScrollBar.o \
    src/widgets/Application.o \
    src/widgets/BitmapFontGL.o \
    src/widgets/TextureGL.o \
    src/widgets/LoadTexture.o \
    src/widgets/Label.o \
    src/widgets/ErrorBox.o \
    src/widgets/TextInput.o \
    src/widgets/RangeSelector.o \
    src

OBJECTS_LINUX = \
    src/widgets/native/FileDialogLinux.o \
    src/native/PathsLinux.o

OBJECTS += $(OBJECTS_LINUX)

CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Isrc -Isupport -I. -Wall -DSIGSLOT_PURE_ISO --std=c++11 `sdl2-config --cflags`
LIBS = `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2_image -lGL -lGLU -lbass -lpthread -lhidapi-libusb

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CCX) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
all:
    $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(TARGET).exe $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS_LINUX)  $(TARGETDIR).zip
    rm -rf $(TARGET).app $(TARGETDIR) _resources.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: You appear to have mis-copied what I posted in answer to [your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934602/undefined-references-when-installing-backyard-brains-spike-recorder/935066?noredirect=1#comment1481408_935066)

Comment: Working version, Ubuntu 16.10 Gnome

Comment: Working version https://hastebin.com/bovuyixabu.tex

Comment: A final version of the working code with an edited OBJECTS list in Makefile is here https://hastebin.com/lahapahule.tex